# XNA Snap sprite to a tile map

Tags: xna, 2d, tiles

I'm looking for the best option on how to handle snapping sprites to a tilemap.  I'm trying to make a Chu Chu Rocket clone.  If you dont know the game.  It is a tilebased game where you place arrows on a specfic tile to direct unts around the maps.  So I need to snap the sprites to the center of the tile at all times and then detect a collision with either an arrow which takes up a whole tile or a wall or other obstruction.  Any ideas on what the based way would be to detect those things since it would require different kinds of collision detection i believe.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to snap the sprites to a tile is to draw them centered at a tile. The collision detection can be done in your update function by checking against your level object.

```
class Mouse
{
  public int XTile;
  public int YTile;
  public int XDelta;
  public int YDelta;
} 

//in Update
if (Level[mouse.YTile][mouse.XTile] == Tiles.Arrow)
{
  //change mouse.XDelta and mouse.YDelta based on the direction of the arrow
}
if (Level[mouse.YTile + YDelta][mouse.XTile + XDelta] == Tiles.Wall)
{
  //change mouse.XDelta and mouse.YDelta based on wall rules
}

//in Draw
int tileSize = 32; //or whatever size tile you are using
spriteBatch.Draw(mouseSprite, new Vector2(mouse.XTile * tileSize, 
    mouse.YTile * tileSize), Color.White);

//or, if the mouseSprite doesn't take up the whole tile
int sizeDifference = tileSize - mouseSprite.Width;
spriteBatch.Draw(mouseSprite, new Vector2(mouse.XTile * tileSize + sizeDifference / 2f, 
    mouse.YTile * tileSize + sizeDifference / 2f), Color.White);
```

Comment: How would you determine Mouse tile location so you would stay centered on the tile?  Would you have to detect if the mouse's bounding box is inside the tile?  If so, how would that work if the mouse is larger than the tile?

Comment: Otherwise how do you know if a tile makes you change direction you would need to be centered on it so to not throw off your path on every change of direction.

Comment: In the example code, I assumed that the mouse would always be centered on a tile, never halfway between two tiles. (This is what I thought you meant by 'snapping a sprite') If this is true, then Mouse stores its tile location through XTile and YTile.

Comment: You shouldn't need to bother with bounding boxes. If mouseSprite is taller than the tile, add a Y offset to the vector during Draw(). Something like: new Vector2(mouse.XTile * tileSize, mouse.YTile * tileSize - mouseSprite.Height + tileSize).
Regarding the change of direction, just change XDelta or YDelta to a constant depending on the arrow direction. It won't matter if it is set to the same thing on subsequent turns.